# A double integration via Fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$$\int_0^1\int_0^\infty ye^{-xy}\sin x\,dx\,dy$$

How can I calculate out the value of this integral?

P.S. One easy way is to calculate this integral over $dy$ first, to get an integral form $\frac{1-e^{-x}(x+1)}{x^2}\sin x$, if I calculated correctly, but I don't know any way to calculate out this value other than a hard work with contour integral.  - so I wonder if there be a way other than this (=integrate over $dy$ and do contour integral)

(I tried some integration by parts and substitutions but it seems it does not work well, probably the $\infty$ at the second integral is crucial. I think this requires capturing a term in the integrand and converting to a further integral, and reverting the order of integral by Fubini's theorem.. but I'm not sure)

Comment: Hint: the inner integral is the Laplace transform of $\sin x.$

Comment: Did you notice that your title asks about Fubini's theorem? Did you try applying it?

Comment: Do the y integral first.

Comment: and given bounds of $x$ and $y$ are independent, you can simply change the order.

Comment: For the comment by Sean Roberson - That's not exactly the Laplace transform, but I see what you mean. It seems I can find an appropriate term by known Laplace formulas.

Comment: For the latter three comments, actually integrating over $y$ first we can obviously get some analytic function of $x$, which is a bit dirty, still we can calculate it via contour integral but I wonder if there can be a simpler way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

According to the integration by parts method, we get that

\begin{align*}
\int e^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x = -e^{-xy}\cos(x) - \int ye^{-xy}\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Applying the same method once again, we obtain that

\begin{align*}
\int ye^{-xy}\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x = ye^{-xy}\sin(x) + \int y^{2}e^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Replacing the second expression into the first, it results that

\begin{align*}
\int e^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x = -e^{-xy}\cos(x) - ye^{-xy}\sin(x) - y^{2}\int e^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

which finally yields that

\begin{align*}
\int ye^{-xy}\sin(x)\mathrm{d}x = -e^{-xy}(\cos(x) + y\sin(x))\times\left(\frac{y}{1 + y^{2}}\right)
\end{align*}

Then you can apply the integration limits.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to apply Fubini’s theorem, indeed

$\begin{align}\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^\infty&\!\!ye^{-xy}\sin x\,dxdy=\!\int_0^1\!\left[-\dfrac{ye^{-xy}(\cos x+y\sin x)}{y^2+1}\right]_0^\infty\!\!dy=\\
&=\int_0^1\dfrac y{y^2+1}dy=\left[\dfrac12\ln\left(y^2+1\right)\right]_0^1=\dfrac12\ln2\;.
\end{align}$

Comment: \so this was solvable by elementary calculus.. silly me lol. Besides, you two gave the same answers at the same time; although I couldn't choose both, I gave +1. Thank you.